# Characteristic polynomial of Matrices with different basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let  $ T:V\leftarrow V $ be a linear transformation. 
Let $B$ and $B_1$ be two bases of $V$.

Now consider the matrix of linear transformation $[M]_{B} ^B$ and $[M]_{B} ^{B_1}$. Does the characteristic polynomial of two matrices are same ?

Notation : $[M]_{B} ^{B_1}$ means Basis of domain is $B$ and Basis of co-domain is $B_1$

I tried to prove it but i didn't solve it. But both characteristic polynomial of both matrices should give same eigenvalue .

Comment: Suppose I have a one-dimensional vector space, and my first basis is $\{v\}$, the second basis is $\{7v\}$, and the linear map $T$ is multiplication by 1.

Comment: So both are different? Does eigenvalue depend on basis??

Comment: If you’re allowed to pick different source and target bases, I think the only thing you can say for sure about an operator is its rank. Pretty much everything else about the matrix can change.

Comment: $[M]_B^{B_1}=T[M]_B^B$ where $T$ is the invertible matrix of transition from $B$ to $B_1$. So you are basically asking whether the eigen-values of $M$ and $TM$ are the same, where $T$ is an arbitrary invertible matrix. The answer is no, and you can easily generate examples to show this.

Comment: What is true instead, is that the matrices $[T]_B^B$ and $[T]_{B_1}^{B_1}$ have the same characteristic polynomial.